# GWT Compilation

Tags: gwt

When we compile a gwt application, the compiler do some permutation

Compiling 6 permutations
      Compiling permutation 0...
      Compiling permutation 1...
      Compiling permutation 2...
      Compiling permutation 3...
      Compiling permutation 4...
      Compiling permutation 5...

I am not getting this what is this six permutation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at these links that explain how gwt compilation works [Distributed GWT compilation 1](http://jectbd.com/?p=993) and [Distributed GWT Compilation – 2](http://jectbd.com/?p=1027)

> produces an **abstract syntax tree** containing all the information needed to produce the JavaScript for all the various permutations of, for example, browser and language. Next is CompilePerms, which is done for each different permutation and produces the JavaScript for that permutation

Comment: If we specify locale in module_name.gwt.xml file and user agent values as different browser names,compiler will generate combination of locale *browser  permutaitons

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your six permutations are coming from the fact that GWT compiles a permutation for each browser ("user agent").

The number of permutations can increase if you add other deferred binding rules, including internationalization, or can be reduced if you only plan on supporting some browsers.